# For loop and while loop performance difference in Python using timeit

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I ran across a code while doing some review, and it had while loop, I being averse to while tried for version of it but it turned out for performed considerably poor. Below is the code

```
import timeit

sp_list = list(range(1,9801))
start = 0
bs = 1000
end = start + bs
content =[]
content1 = []
s="""\
while sp_list[start:end]:
    sp_batch = sp_list[start:end]
    for sp in sp_batch:
        content.append(sp*sp)
    start += bs
    end += bs
"""
print("S")
x = timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=100, setup='sp_list = list(range(1,9801));start = 0;bs = 1000;end = start + bs;content =[]')
print(x)

s1="""\
for i in range(1, len(sp_list), bs):
    content1.extend([x*x for x in sp_list[i:i+bs]])
"""

x1 = timeit.timeit(stmt=s1, number=100, setup='sp_list = list(range(1,9801));start = 0;bs = 1000;end = start + bs;content1 =[]')
print(x1)
```

And following is the output.

```
('WHILE ', 0.0013229846954345703)
('FOR ', 0.05230712890625)
```

Why does for loop perform considerably slow? Or am I missing a basic trick here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not confusing the output (eg your code has `print("S")` and no 'WHILE ' or 'FOR ')?

There can some cleanup that can be done to make your original code a great [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

- one has to be able to get the same output as you do from the code, and here it is not the case, which adds to a little confusion.
- some repeated code can be omitted

I added a multiple to `9801` to make the code run longer and the result on 
my machine is that a `for` loop is faster. Not using `timeit()` function, but the result folds on many iterations.

```
import time

sp_list = list(range(1,9801*100))
start = 0
bs = 1000
end = start + bs

# experiment 1
now = time.time()

content = []
while sp_list[start:end]:
    sp_batch = sp_list[start:end]
    for sp in sp_batch:
        content.append(sp*sp)
    start += bs
    end += bs    

exp = time.time() - now

# experiment 2
now = time.time()
content = []

for i in range(1, len(sp_list), bs):
    content.extend([x*x for x in sp_list[i:i+bs]])

exp2 = time.time() - now


print(exp, exp2)
# 0.2183971405029297 0.12479853630065918
```

A list comprehension has a little advantage over loop too:

```
now = time.time()
content = [x*x for i in range(1, len(sp_list), bs) for x in sp_list[i:i+bs]]
exp3 = time.time() - now
print(exp3)
# 0.09359884262084961
```

Comment: You are right @Evgeny , timeit seems to do things fast with while loop.
I measured time with time and all the time for loop is faster and list comprehension is the best.

Comment: So the result depends on measurement type... would be interesting if someone had an explaination for that.